# Blending mode CSS3

Tags: css, blending

I am trying to implement something like [this](https://www.epicurrence.com/) letter on an image with blending mode.

Here is my *[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elene/tym8dcxf/2/)*

```
<div id="box">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="https://www.epicurrence.com/images/speakers/julie.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="overlay">J</div>
</div>
```

Can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using `background-blend-mode` on your `img`. `background-blend-mode` is used to blend multiple background images or colours applied *to the same element*.

`mix-blend-mode` allows you to apply blending to arbitrary elements that are stacked. in your case you should be using `mix-blend-mode` on the top most element (`.overlay`).

```css
#box {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: white;
}

#image img {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -300px;
  font-size: 1000px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease-in-out;  
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="https://www.epicurrence.com/images/speakers/julie.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="overlay">J</div>
</div>
```